# .htaccess modrewrite failing when extending number of GET parameters required

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following code works well for taking a URL path like:

`domain.com/file/value` and redirecting to `file.php?page=value`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/.+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1.php?page=$2 [L]
```

However, the following modification doesn't extend the functionality in the way I expect for `domain.com/file/value/datestring` and redirecting to `file.php?page=value&date=datestring`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/.+$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ /$1.php?page=$2&date=$3 [L]
```

I've tried a few combinations and nothing seems to work, resulting in a 404.

Can anyone help me see what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not including another capture in the rewriterule pattern. You need to add another capture group for the rewrite pattern so there are `three`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$ /$1.php?page=$2&date=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Added the extra condition minus the '/?' and it worked.